How to write a formula to match a month prior to today's date with a date field on the contact
I'm using this formula from the Salesforce community board post to find one month prior to a work anniversary date.
[DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(ADDMONTHS(Date,-1)),DAY(ADDMONTHS(Date,-1)))]
In my flow, I then compare the current date to the date produced by the formula. An email will be sent if the dates are a match. However, I don't think the formula is not taking into account the differing number of days per month. For example, if an employee's work anniversary will fall on May 31st, the suggested reminder date will be April 31st, which isn't a date. March gets tricky, too, due to the variance of days in February. Any suggestions?

All of the details of handling dates (and there are a lot more details than most people realize) are handled automatically when using ADDMONTHS() and also when adding/subtracting a number of days, e.g. TODAY() - 3
You are correct in being concerned about using the results of that in DATE() though.
ADDMONTHS(DATE(2024-05-31), -1) results in 2024-04-30, so a work anniversary of 05-31 isn't going to cause an issue.
ADDMONTHS(DATE(2024-05-30), -1) would also result in 2024-04-30
If you end up with something like DATE(2025, 2, 29) or DATE(2021, 6, 31), Salesforce won't complain when you try to save the formula, but it'll either be null when you go to use it, result in some error, or perhaps both.
The only scenario you need to worry about is the end of March. If you're ok with the formula giving a result that's 1 day early on leap years (which shouldn't be that big of a stretch if you're ok with 05-30 and 05-31 both becoming 04-30), then you can simply use an IF() to handle that scenario.
IF(
    /* March 29th, 30th, and 31st present problems */
    MONTH(Date) = 3 && DAY(Date) >= 29,

    /* For safety, just make the end of March result in February 28th */
    DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), 2, 28),

    /* Otherwise, just let ADDMONTHS() work its magic */
    /* As long as you use ADDMONTHS() for both the Month and Day, it'll be fine */
    DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(ADDMONTHS(Date, -1)), DAY(ADDMONTHS(Date, -1)))
)


Thanks! This worked perfectly. I appreciate the explanation as well!
